# Is Pinch To Zoom in TextEdit feature available in Lion?

Tags: macos, multi-touch, textedit

In Mountain Lion it is now possible Pinch To Zoom in files within TextEdit. I think this is a new feature in Mountain Lion.

I'd like to know whether it is available in Lion?

Answer (score 1):

No, not at the moment.  They decided to remove it in Mountain Lion for some reason...but they'll probably add it back due to complaints.

Comment: They didn't remove this feature in ML.